# Blazor WASM Button Onclick not firing every time

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a table with the summary of items, and when i click on a button i have a modal pop up with addition information about that item. Unfortunately, for some reason, Blazor will not always pop up the modal. It's gotten to the point where i've simplified the code to just do a Console.WriteLine("Person Id: Id") and i'm still seeing the issue.

```
@foreach(var p in people){
  <tr>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" @onclick="(async()=>await ShowPerson(p))">@p.FirstName</button>
    </td>
    <td>@p.LastName</td>
  </tr>
}
```

then in the code section

```
List<Person> people { get; set; }
...
async Task ShowPerson(Person p){
  Console.WriteLine("Click");
  selectedPerson = p;
  await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("toggleModal", "personModal");
}
```

then in my js file the toggleModal just does a `$("#" + id).modal('toggle');`

now when i'm watching the console, I can click a button and there is a chance that nothing shows up in the console, and the modal doesn't open. Or the Click shows up in the console and the modal pops up. Has anyone come across this, or see anything obvious from the code above?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who comes across this and is as blind as i am. Verify that your `@onclick` is on the actual button and not on the span within

Bad:

```
<button class="btn btn-success">
  <span class="fa fa-bug" @onclick="(async()=>await foo(x))"></span>
</button>
```

Good:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="(async()=>await foo(x))">
  <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little surprised it didn't fire anyway, to be honest.  You can put @onclick on almost anything.

Comment: It did fire when I was clicking on the icon, but since I was sometimes hitting the button and not the icon it wouldn't trigger so the issue seemed intermittent

Comment: Ah, so it's kind of clicking "around" elements in the span.  That makes sense.  I'm pretty sure if it was a div, it would work anywhere.  I do that a lot-- I'll throw an underline and a blue color on a div, and the text looks clickable-- then I'll use @onclick to unfold the next layer of a tree or something.